# After getting a new passport, are Canadian student and visitors visas still valid for entry?

Tags: visas, canada, passport-renewals, tanzanian-citizens

My daughter has Canadian student visa valid for 4 years and visitor visa valid for 8 years. Her passport is valid until 2025 but Tanzania's government has imposed a new law that requires every citizen to have the new e-passport before the end of 2019.

My daughter is coming back to her own country in 2019 to be issued the new e-passport. Does she have to reapply for new student and visitor visas or she can travel with both the old and new passports to enter Canada?

Comment: Can she not get a new passport from the Tanzanian consulate or embassy in Canada?

Comment: No She can't get a new passport from the Tanzanian consulate or embassy in Canada As per  Government  law she to come to his own country

Comment: I am not sure if there are separate laws pertaining to your country. But I have a new passport (since the old one expires) but have my US visa in the old one. Whenever I travel internationally, I carry both of them and I haven't had any problem at any of the borders. On my old passport, there's a stamp that says 'CANCELLED' since it expired, you should look out if they put a similar stamp on your daughter's older passport.

Answer (score 3):

I'm from Kuwait and have the same thing. I did get a new e-Passport. I went to Canada carrying both my old and new passport together.

Also if you have multiple visas make sure to tell the officer which one you want to use. As they need to know are you coming as a tourist or a student if you have both visas.

There was no problems at all. When you arrive in Canada. Make sure to show the "Visa page" and the new Passport and tell the officer that.

I have also tried this with US B1/B2 and Schengen visitor visa all while having a new passport.

Cheers,
Shbli